# Validator on reset password laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm installing a new laravel application, long story short, I got reset password function worked by `php artisan make:auth`

But I need to change the reset password min length to 4, the framework doesn't let me.

My attempt so far

This is `ResetPasswordController.php`

```
    class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
     */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
        ];
    }
}
```

This function works, when I tried to submit a 3 character, the error showed up correctly. `The password must be at least 4 characters.`

However, If I submit 4 characters, this error showed up `Passwords must be at least eight characters and match the confirmation.`
After looking at laravel documentation
this function `/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php` `@validatePasswordWithDefaults` is the culprit. [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php)

Is this a bug? or just me that don't know how to use the reset password feature?
Thanks for the help

Comment: post the rest password reset

Comment: @MartinHenriksen I have put the rest of password reset

Comment: @MartinHenriksen I've found the answer, thanks for helping!

Comment: please try to override the function rules() with the protected visibility: `protected function rules()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `rules` function, override `reset` function.
Here's mine now, working.

```
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
        ], $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $this->broker()->validator(function ($credentials) {
            return mb_strlen($credentials['password']) >= 6;
        });
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Laravel 7** works by adding the below code in your `ResetPasswordController.php`

```
protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
        ];
    }
```

**Note:** it overrides the **rules function** of `ResetsPasswords.php` located in `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend` folder.